# NSManagedObjectContext merge from private context, refresh only changed objects

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**Facts:**

- I use CoreData.
- I have parent object with child rows, where children might well exceed 500 objects.
- I show those child objects in `UITableViewController` `UITableView`.
- I have set up it to work with `NSFetchedResultsController`, allowing me to get updates as soon as something changes. And I need that.
- I am merging changes from private context to main context with the following code:

  ```
  @objc func privateContextDidSaveNotification(notification: NSNotification)
  {            
      let savedContext = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext

      if savedContext == self.managedObjectContext
      {
          return   // This is the Main context
      }

      if savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator != self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator
      {
          return   // This is different DB
      }

      self.managedObjectContext.performBlockAndWait(
      {
          self.managedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
          self.managedObjectContext.refreshAllObjects()
      })
  }
  ```
- `NSFetchedResultsController.delegate` is set only on child objects.

**Problem:**

If even one child object for this parent object changes, the 
`func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
        didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
        atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?,
        forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
        newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?)` gets called for all child rows, meaning, it's called >500 times, and basically, the app freezes.

**What I Discovered:**

1. The update notifications for all child objects is caused by this line after merge: `self.managedObjectContext.refreshAllObjects()`.
2. If I remove that line, then `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't receive any notification that something is updated at all - but I need that.

**Questions:**

1. How can I make  that one particular row of changed child object, meaning - how can I notify `NSFetchedResultsController` only actually changed rows?
2. What's the typical solution to notify NSFetchedResultsController about merged objects?

Thanks a lot!

Maris

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `NSPersistentContainer`to setup your stack.
The new containers `viewContext` and `backgroundContext` automatically send and consume notifications and merge them from the `PersistentStoreCordinator`.

This way you don't need to manage the merge yourself and the `NSFetchedResultController`, that will be setup on the `viewContext` will update